# Vue project "npm run dev" results in "This site cannot be reached error"

Tags: vue.js, npm

When I run "npm run dev" for my Vue project it says it compiled correctly but 0.0.0.0:8080 says "This site can't be reached". I have also tried localhost:8080 and gotten the same result.

I don't know if this matters, but the current version of vue on my computer is version 3.11.0

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Edit: Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "a-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "An Author",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "gsap": "^2.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "prejs": "^1.2.6",
    "v-money": "^0.8.1",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.9",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-scroll-stop": "^0.1.5",
    "vue-youtube-embed": "^2.2.1",
    "vue2-filters": "^0.3.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^8.5.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "1.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^13.7.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 [isn't a valid address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) to go visit in the browser. Have you tried `localhost:8080`?

Comment: Yeah, i get the same issue

Comment: Show us your `package.json`.

Comment: It is added now

Comment: Can you show the console output when you run `npm run dev`?

Comment: Anyone find a fix for this problem?